# VBA: Tickbox - True, creates a sheet. False, deletes the sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am editing an existing template in VBA. This template organises data from a "Raw Data" sheet into a "Day", "Evening" and "Night" sheet. I want to create a sheet called "Weekend", where data from "Raw Data" will be copied to if the date is not a weekday (i know how to do that bit).

However, the amount of data that runs through this template is massive, so to avoid creating a weekend sheet where the user does not need/want one I want to put in a section of code where if a tick box is ticked (True), a sheet called "Weekend" will be created (within the workbook, but inbetween existing sheets - namely inbetween a sheet called "Night" and "Graph - All Data") and when it is unticked (False) this sheet will not exist.

I thought about having this sheet to exist all the time, and to have it hidden when the tick box is unticked, however this means that the data would be still piled into it and in the interest of efficiency I would rather not have it like that.

Here is the Code I am trying to alter

```
Sub ToggleWindDirection()

Dim i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If sheetArr(1) Is Nothing And LastNDRow = Empty Then
    DefineLists
End If

Sheets("Raw Data").Unprotect Password:="2260"
For Each sht In sheetArr
    sht.Unprotect Password:="2260"
Next

Set chtAllData = ActiveWorkbook.Charts("Graph - All Data")

    With Sheets("Raw Data")

        If .Range("O15").Value = True Then
        'Wind direction is being used
            .Range("C17:G17").Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Range("D17").Font.ColorIndex = 9
            .Range("G17").Font.ColorIndex = 9
            .Range("D17").Locked = False
            .Range("G17").Locked = False

            .Range("F" & FirstNDRow & ":F10000").Interior.Pattern = xlNone
            .Range("F" & FirstNDRow & ":F10000").Interior.PatternTintAndShade = 0
        .Range("F" & FirstNDRow & ":F10000").Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic

    Else
    'Not using wind direction
        .Range("C17:G17").Font.ColorIndex = 16
        .Range("D17").Locked = True
        .Range("G17").Locked = True

        .Range("F" & FirstNDRow & ":F10000").Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
        .Range("F" & FirstNDRow & ":F10000").Interior.TintAndShade = -4.99893185216834E-02
        .Range("F" & FirstNDRow & ":F10000").Font.ColorIndex = 16

    End If


'Addition by lewisthegruffalo 2016

Dim ws As Worksheet

    If .Range("O21").Value = True Then
    'create the weekend sheet
        Set ws = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets("Night"))
        ws.Name = "Weekend"
    Else
    'No Weekend needed
        Worksheets("Weekend").Delete
    End If

End With

Sheets("Raw Data").Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly apprichiated.

Kind Regards,

lewisthegruffalo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a new sheet using sheets.add then you can utilise the arguments in it to tell it where to put it, [the msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839847.aspx) has a good example at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

What you have so far? Where do you wanna call it? What checkbox shall be ticked? Please provide some code.

A general answer is this to add a new worksheet:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
If Something Then
 Set ws = Worksheets.Add(Before:=Worksheets("Graph - All Data"))
 ws.Name = "Weekend"
 'do anything you want with the ws object
End if
```

Comment: Hi @Mono sorry for the amount of time i have left this, I have been away from the computer.

Comment: So far i have a 'homepage' (so to speak) where i can input variables defining what sort of time would be appropriate to consider "Night" or "Day" etc, there is also a few other tick boxes that ask if the weather data that is also collected is to be taken into consideration. When these are unticked (i.e. they are immedietly greyed out and "locked"  throught the `.Locked = True` method. Hope this helps

Comment: Also, @Mono, i tried your `ws = Worksheet.add(` section and it have me an error type 1004 with message "Method 'Add' of object 'Sheets' failed, any advice, kind regards

Comment: POst your complete code else I cant help you at all. I also wrote Worksheets.Add not Worksheet

Comment: Try to use Sheets.add instead of Worksheets.add, as you are using Charts and Worksheets.

Comment: Is the whole workbook maybe protected? Can you add sheets manually ?

Comment: The workbook was protected @Mono, thanks for your help!